# Equivalent of a "fan page" in Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

Is it possible to create a Google+ page for my product/company, that people can plussify and add in their circles?

If yes, how to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After a few months of testing, [Google+ pages](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/google-pages-connect-with-all-things.html) are available. 
You can now create public pages for brands, products, local businesses and more by going to [Create a Page](https://plus.google.com/pages/create#pages/create).

Although it looks like regular user profiles, but there are [differences](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1713824&topic=1710599):

> - Pages can’t add people to circles until the page is added first or    mentioned.
> - Pages can be made for a variety of different entities whereas    profiles can only be made for people.
> - The default privacy setting for elements on your page profile is    public.
> - Pages have the +1 button.
> - Pages can’t +1 other pages, nor can they +1 stuff on the Web.
> - Pages don’t have the option to share to ‘Extended circles’.
> - Pages don’t receive notifications via email, text, or in the Google    bar.
> - Pages can’t hangout on a mobile device.
> - Local pages have special fields that help people find the business’    physical location. Learn more about local pages.

So finally, People can add pages to one of their circles, +1'd the page, and share it to their streams.

Example Page: [Google+ Your Business](https://plus.google.com/pages/create#115200251016762857369/posts).