# How to create a Google+ business profile?

Tags: google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent of a “fan page” in Google+?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/equivalent-of-a-fan-page-in-google)

I have seen that some sites like IGN, PCGamer, etc. have created, few hours ago, their Google+ profiles. I suppose then that Google removed the previous limitations.

Where can I create a business profile for my web community? I search around and didn't find how to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/17522/1873